# Android сохранение небольших данных

Tags: android

как можно хранить небольшие данные в приложении, чтобы не грузить их из базы данных.

Под небольшими данными понимается, например, последний пользователь и его пароль, который прошел авторизацию приложения, его настройки (выбор города) и т.д.

И как можно использовать эти данные во всем приложении, чтобы их не передавать между layout'ами в параметрах Intent?

Comment: Читайте про ```Preferences```

Answer (score 2):

Вот вам не большой пример использования. Тут сохраняется email(можете добавить еще полей или объектов). Я вынес в отдельный класс, для уменьшения дублирования кода.

```
public class UserSharedPreferense implements UserState {

    private static final String APP_PREFERENCES = "mysettings";
    private static final String APP_PREFERENCES_EMAIL = "Email";
    public static final String DEFAULT_VALUE = "default";

    private SharedPreferences sPref;

    public UserSharedPreferense(Context context) {
        this.sPref = context.getSharedPreferences(
                APP_PREFERENCES, context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return sPref.getString(APP_PREFERENCES_EMAIL, DEFAULT_VALUE);
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sPref.edit();
        editor.putString(APP_PREFERENCES_EMAIL, email);
        editor.commit();
    }
}
```

Для него интерфейс

```
    public interface UserState {
    String getEmail();

    void setEmail(String email);
}
```

Сохраняю экземпляр в `Application` не забудьте объявить его в манифесте

```
public class App extends Application {
   private UserState sharedPref;

    public UserState getSharedPref() {
        return sharedPref;
    }

    public void setSharedPref(UserState userState) {
        this.sharedPref = userState;
    }
    }
```

При старте проекта (в загрузочном активити) инициализируем

```
userSharedPreferense = new UserSharedPreferense(this);

((App) getApplication()).setSharedPref(userSharedPreferense);
```

Теперь в любом месте вызываем

```
String email =  ((App) getApplication()).getSharedPref().getEmail(); 
((App) getApplication()).getSharedPref().setEmail(email);
```

Конечно вы можете упростить и не добавлять интерфейс. И не закидывать в `Application`. Ну по мне это сэкономит ваше время, а так же уменьшит дублирование кода.