# Форма согласия для пользователей из ЕЭЗ

Tags: android

Я новичок в программировании, поэтому мне очень нужна помощь при внедрении формы согласия на показ рекламы AdMob и хотелось бы поподробнее, ато уже больше недели мучаюсь. Интересует код, который должен находится в MainActivity и остальные ньюансы.
Заранее всем огромное спасибо!

Comment: Вот тут есть ссылка на SDK как раз для этих целей: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/833578/%d0%97%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%be%d1%82-%d0%b5%d0%b2%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%b5%d0%b9%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8%d1%85-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b9-admob?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 1):

Для этого нам понадобиться хранение данных. В данном случае мы будет сохранять в `SharedPreferences`. Не давно отвечал как это можно сделать вот тут [SharedPreferences хранение данных](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/829607/android-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%85-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85/829639#829639). В вашем случае будем сохранять переменную (можно int, String и так далее) как вам удобней. Что мы делаем. В MainActivity мы обращаемся к нашей переменной. Если значение дефолтное то мы вызываем диалоговое окно (код приводить не буду, примеров много). Ответ пользователя сохраняем в нашу переменную.  Из ссылки выше, где нам нужно отобразить рекламу(баннер, объявление). Обращаемся к переменной `((App) getApplication()).getSharedPref().setEmail(email);`. И оталкиваясь от неё мы показываем или не показываем нашу рекламу.

Надеюсь я достаточно хорошо смог объяснить ход решения. Если нет, обращайтесь.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, Виталий. А для SharedPreferences нужны какие либо разрешения в манифесте?

Comment: Если вы будете использовать  подход как в ответе. То для манифеста нужно будет указать Application  класс

Comment: Спасибо большое, все получилось.

Comment: Отлично. Отметьте тогда как ответ, возможно кому-нибудь еще пригодится)